# what is the reason that favicon doesnt appear on the main web browser

Tags: favicon, web-services

my favicon isnt appearing on the google search results how can i fix it?
[image: where i want to add picture]

i have tried all possible ways: putting code in header.php
adding it from media library

adding it from site identity

adding code in function.php

Comment: Does the favicon work in general, i.e. is it at /favicon.ico or are there the right headers for it on your homepage? Assuming that's right I'd look at your Google webmaster console / search console and see if there are any more details or configuration you'd need to do there. I'm not sure there's anything specific we can do.